# TypeScript allows a function as React prop that conflicts with in-param of function signature?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Why does the TypeScript type checker allow a prop with a function parameter that does not strictly match the definition?

Specifically I define a function `callbackImpl = (str: string): number`, and give it as a React prop parameter defined as `callback(parameter: string | undefined): number;`, which surprisingly works.

This is unintuitive to me, and in my opinion quite dangerous!

But! It does not work to call `callbackImpl(undefined)` which I think is correct.

A complete example:

```
import React from "react";

interface Props {
    callback(parameter: string | undefined): number;
}

class A extends React.Component<Props> {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.callback(undefined);
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {

    private callbackImpl = (str: string): number => {
        // Will crash if str is undefined
        return str.length;
    };

    // THIS IS NOT ALLOWED! And rightly so!
    private callLocalWithUndefined() {
        // TS2345: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
        this.callbackImpl(undefined);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <A
                    // This is obviously just as illegal as what happens in callLocalWithUndefined,
                    // since callbackImpl explicitly does not accept undefined as the first parameter,
                    // but no type errors here!?
                    callback={this.callbackImpl}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

I have set `"strict": true,` in `tsconfig.json`

Here is a more complete `tsconfig.json` listing, with some local stuff omitted.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "plugins": [],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      // Omitted
    },
    "lib": [
      "es2017", // Object.entries support
      "dom"
    ],
    "types": ["gapi", "gapi.auth2", "node"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are my tsconfig settings wrong? Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

## Edit

Additional resources after the answer by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir

- [Strict Function Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html) as described by the TS 2.6 Release Notes. Describes that methods are not covered by Strict Function Type checking.
- And in the [regular documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictFunctionTypes)

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the added code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right this is unsafe. There was a rationale for allowing this behavior to ease migration from JS to TS. The good news you can opt into not allowing this by using `strictFunctionTypes`.

For example this code

```
declare const callbackImpl: (str: string) => number

let callback: (parameter: string | undefined) => number;

callback = callbackImpl

callback(undefined);
```

The code above compiles with `strictNullChecks` even though it's not fully type safe as you noticed. But it will fail to compile with both `strictNullChecks` and `strictFunctionTypes`

**Note** I assumed you are already using `strictNullChecks` if you are not then the code works as expected because without this option `string|undefined` is by definition just `string`

**Edit**

The above generic explanation was posted before the question included the actual code. The reason the compiler does not catch the error is because you define callback as a method. If you define it as function field, the compiler catches the error. <strike>I am still unsure why</strike> See below:

```
interface Props {
    callback: (parameter: string | undefined) => number;
}

class A extends React.Component<Props> {
    componentDidUpdate() {
        this.props.callback(undefined);
    }
}

class B extends React.Component {

    private callbackImpl = (str: string): number => {
        // Will crash if str is undefined
        return str.length;
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <A
                  // Error now
                    callback={this.callbackImpl}
                />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit**

This behavior is by design. The `-strictFunctionTypes` flag does not apply to methods as stated in the original [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/18654)

> The stricter checking applies to all function types, except those originating in method or construcor declarations. Methods are excluded specifically to ensure generic classes and interfaces (such as Array) continue to mostly relate covariantly. The impact of strictly checking methods would be a much bigger breaking change as a large number of generic types would become invariant (even so, we may continue to explore this stricter mode).

Comment: Thanks for the update. If you find out why it works with a function field but not a method I would be very happy =)

Comment: Thanks! That is quite a caveat - unintuitive and dangerous. I personally can't wait for WebAssembly to rid us of the ridiculous JavaScript legacy.